# PHP include svg assets in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, svg, include

Does cake have a way to php include svg assets?  I know how to use helpers to create an `<img>` tag pointing to the SVG for the img's src attribute, but I'd like to actually include the file rather than reference it within an `<img>` tag.

Comment: How do you want to access SVG?

Comment: I'd like to inline it so I can manipulate with css.

Comment: Do you know what CSS style? (HTML)

Comment: Animating paths within the SVG

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_and_CSS

Comment: The Animations I wrote work fine.  I just thought there may be a better way to inline my svg other than just having the giant code block in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this was a silly question.  You can of course just use `<?php include 'img/thefile.svg' ?>` assuming your svg is in `webroot/img` folder.  If the svg or file is not in a publicly accessible folder I would look to creating a custom helper as another post suggested.

Answer (score 1):

No, CakePHP doesn't ship with such functionality, you'll have to come up with something on your own, or use one of the many PHP based SVG inliners out there, it should be easy enough to wrap that in a custom helper.

If you just need to embed the file, then you could even stick to simply reading and outputting the file contents with the XML declaration and doctype removed, something like:

```
$svg = file_get_contents($path);
$svg = preg_replace('/^<\?xml.*?\?>\s*(<!DOCTYPE.*?>\s*)?/is', '', $svg);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Custom helper seems like a clean reusable solution.  Cheers.